# What Camel EIP pattern to use to indicate EOF?

Tags: java, integration, apache-camel, esb

I have a scenario where I am processing a large log file by ingesting it onto a Camel-based ESB. The first stop on this bus is a processor - `LogTransformer` - that parses log messages out of the log file, one by one (real-time), and creates XML snippets:

```
<log-record level="INFO" source="MyApp" .../>
```

Each one of these `<log-record/>` XML snippets gets put onto a message queue and gets picked up by the bus. Eventually it winds up in a MySQL DB.

I have certain processors that I want to kick off *only* after the log file is completely processed (all log records have been converted to `<log-record/>` and enqueued, processed by the bus, and stored to the DB). Things like report generators, BI components, etc. These processors shouldn't begin until the entire log is enqueued.

**What's the Camel way of automatically indicating to these processors that they can kick off?**

The best I can come up with is to have my `LogTransformer` processor (the part that parses log records, transforms them to `<log-record>` XML, and enqueues them) create an EOF log record *after* it finishes processing the log. Something like `<log-record eof="true">`. It then enqueues this message like normal.

When the last processor in the bus (which persists `<log-record>` to MySQL) encounters the EOF log record, instead of persisting it, it enqueues it on a queue.

These report generators, BI components, etc. wait for a message on this queue to kick off.

This solution seems convoluted. I'm brand new to ESBs, and Camel, so I figured there would be an EIP/processor that handles this scenario, but I can't seem to find it. How would a Camel Wizard structure this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Splitter (http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) and Aggregator (http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html).  The aggregator can use completionSize to determine that it has all of the pieces it needs to continue processing.

Comment: Thanks @JimN (+1) - what if my log file has 100 million log records in it? I don't think I can have a single `Aggregator` holding 100M record in memory! Any other solution to "flag" to other processors that they can begin executing?

Comment: Your aggregator doesn't need to aggregate (cache) all of the data records.  It can just be used as a sentinel to determine when all log records have been seen.